# error in Java script link don't work in visual s code

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

i put link of javascript in my html code for the fa-bars in want to use it but don't work .. any help i guss the problem in vs because when is copy the code to the codepen it is work.    `<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`  this is link js in header.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
        <lable for="check" class="checkbtn">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>

        </lable>
```

**this is the fa- bar in nav.**

Comment: I don't think there can be any problem with the editor (in your case vscode). I am having a feeling that you spelt `label` really wrong. It is `label` and not `lable`

Comment: Could you provide some information on the problem. Do you get any errors within the Dev Tools console, for example?

Comment: @bladeski don't problem in the vs code it is not show the fa-bar and i don't why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `<script>` tag you provided isn't working. Use the `link` tag instead, with `.css` version of font awesome.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.0/css/all.css" />

<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<label for="check" class="checkbtn">
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's spelt label, not lable. Fix the typo in your tags

Comment: thank you i fix it but, stil don't work for me :(